# Is there a way to use bull rush maneuvers to crush enemies against walls and other terrain for extra damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, combat-maneuver, terrain

For an illustration of what I'm looking for, see [this link](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0808.html).

Anyway, by the basic rules, sending an enemy against an obstacle with a bull rush simply ends the forced movement without any additional effect. I found the [Awesome Blow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/awesome-blow) feat to send enemies fly with a strong melee attack, but the distance pushed is pretty low and it doesn't allow to move with the target.

Then is there any feat that I missed that allows to bull rush enemies hard enough to crush them against obstacles for extra damage ?

Comment: Is Dungeons and Dragons 3.5 content okay, or just Pathfinder?

Comment: This is subject to caution since a few feats from D&D 3.5 became specific class features in Pathfinder and a lot of them simply didn't make it, mostly to make some classes more interesting and because some of them were too insane (like using your Strength modifier for ranged attack rolls with thrown weapons, removed because it made Strength-focused characters ridiculously powerful, or feinting with ranged attacks, now a Rogue talent).

Answer (score 5):

If *D&D 3.5* is acceptable then this alternative class feature and these feats may be of benefit.

The fighter alternative class feature **Dungeon Crasher** (*Dungeonscape* 10) replaces the 2nd and 6th level bonus feats.

> #### Replaces
>
> If you select this alternative class feature, you do not gain
> the fighter bonus feats at 2nd level and at 6th level.
>
> #### Benefit
>
> You excel at overwhelming traps, smashing through doors, and pushing
> aside your enemies. At 2nd level, you gain a +2 competence bonus on
> saves and to your Armor Class when attacked by traps. You also gain a
> +5 bonus on Strength checks to break a door, wall, or similar obstacle.
>
> In addition, you gain a special benefit when making a bull
> rush. If you force an opponent to move into a wall or other solid
> object, he stops as normal. However, your momentum crushes him against
> it, dealing an amount of bludgeoning damage equal to 4d6 points +
> twice your Strength bonus (if any).
>
> At 6th level, the bonuses when
> dealing with traps increase to +4, and the bonus on Strength checks to
> break objects increases to +10. The damage you deal when bull rushing
> an opponent into a wall increases to 8d6 points + three times your
> Strength bonus.

Typically this is combined with the feat **Shock Trooper** (*Complete Warrior* 112) and/or the feat **Knockback** (*Races of Stone* 142).

This combination of feats is a good way to incorporate bowling mini-games into your RPG sessions.

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to mention, the comic is based on 3.5 rules, not pathfinder. So he will have more chances of duplicating those effects with 3.5 rules.

Comment: This webcomic is based off D&D 3,5, then it's likely that the half-orc (who claims earlier in the comic that he only took two fighter levels "for the extra feats" and the rest in barbarian) has the Dungeon Crasher alternate class features.

Comment: @HeyICanChan What does “campsite theory” mean?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie If you visit a campsite, you're supposed to leave it better than when you found it. (It makes me uncomfortable to clean up *only* the bare minimum when I can make things better.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Aha! Yes, that makes sense; that's even encouraged by [SE's guidance for editing](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). The edit note just [confused the author (and me)](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6498/use-real-headers-instead-of-fake-headers?noredirect=1#comment19860_6498), so I felt the need to ask. Thank you for your conscientiousness!

Answer (score 2):

What you want seems to be exactly what [Street Styles](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/street-style-combat-style) covers:

> You use the urban environment to your advantage, thrashing and bashing your foe and driving it back

Do note that they are *fighting unarmed* on that strip.

But knowing that the half-orc is a [barbarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian), he is very likely using the [Knockback rage power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/knockback-ex).

Otherwise, aparently they are just [grapplin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple)g at each other with cinematographic damage to the enviroment due to their massive strength for being the two strongest guys in the comic. The *fluff* of grapple allows you to say something like "*i hit his head against the pillar*".